# How do I use a database entry to render a style in React Native?

Tags: reactjs, react-native

I want to style list items in my React Native app based on a style name saved for each item in my database. The style name in the database references a "class" in my styles but I'm not sure how to call the "class" correctly in my `view` so it renders the style.

Database entry (here `redItem` is a class name):

```
var ITEMS_DATA = [
{location: 'Manhattan', color: 'redItem'} ];
```

View:

```
<TouchableHighlight key={i} style={[styles.listItem, styles.{{item.color}}]}>
<View>
    <Text style={CardStyles.gameSection}>{item.location}</Text>
</View> </TouchableHighlight>
```

Style from StyleSheet:

```
redItem: { backgroundColor: '#e91e63' },
```

Note the `styles.{{game.color}}` in `TouchableHighlight` - this is where I want to pull in styles via the referenced class name.

Currently when I load this is the simulator I get a `SyntaxError`.

Please note that I'm a very junior programmer. Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

To access a dynamically named property from a Javascript object, you use `object[name]`. In your case, you would access it with `styles[item.color]`. This would look as follows in your code snippet:

```
<TouchableHighlight key={i} style={[styles.listItem, styles[item.color]]}>
<View>
    <Text style={CardStyles.gameSection}>{item.location}</Text>
</View> </TouchableHighlight>
```

I tested this locally, and accessing properties of a `StyleSheet` like this is working.